# Saving Slope Coefficients in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, regression

I am working with a dataset that contains both numerical and dummy variables. I am trying to figure out how to regress Y (my dependent variable) on a dummy variable x (x = 1 if condition is true and 0 otherwise but I want to do it by category, Z, which is nationality so that I end up with the regression coefficients for each nationality. My final goal is to plot each of the regression coefficients against another variable M. I cannot figure out how to regress y = b0 +b1x by nationality so that after that I can plot all my b1's, here is my attempt of doing so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats as stats
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import matplotlib . pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns



df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.head()
df.dtypes
df.columns 


model1 = df.groupby('z').apply(lambda df: smf.ols(formula = 'y ~ C(x)', data = df).fit())
                                              
model1.params  #I get a 'Series' object has no attribute 'params' message  


model1[1]
final_sample.insert(1,'model1',model1)
#I run this code but nothing is plotted. I am not sure how I should 
#save the coefficients from above.
final_sample.plot(x='m', y='model1', style='o')
plt.title('Title')
plt.xlabel('X label')
plt.ylabel('Y label')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model1 = df.groupby('z').apply(lambda df: smf.ols(formula = 'y ~ C(x)', data = df).fit())
```

What this lines creates is a pandas.Series (a single column) with one model per group of z. That is why you cannot access your parameters with model1.params.

Instead try this to get a table with model params per each group of z:

```
model_params = df.groupby('z').apply(lambda df: smf.ols(formula = 'y ~ C(x)', data = df).fit().params)
```

Comment: Yes, this modification indeed creates a table in the format I was looking for.